# Cubic Interpolation doesn't show, but linear does?

Tags: python, matlab, plot, scipy, interpolation

So I made a few data points and I plotted them. Then, I wanted to interpolate and plot its cubic function. However, when I plotted, only 3 of the functions showed up. How do I make it so all functions show? Additionally, when I plotted the interpolated linear function, all lines showed up nicely.

```
xnew = np.linspace(0.0414, 1.0414, 10000)

z, mass1, mass2, mass3, mass4, mass5, mass6, mass7 = np.loadtxt("BHMF_bluemassfinal.dat", usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], unpack = True)
axes[0].plot(z, mass1,'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass2, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass3, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass4, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass5, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass6, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(z, mass7, 'bo')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb1(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb2(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb3(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb4(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb5(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb6(xnew), 'k')
axes[0].plot(xnew, fb7(xnew), 'k')

z, mass1, mass2, mass3, mass4, mass5, mass6, mass7 = np.loadtxt("BHMF_greenmassfinal.dat", usecols = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7], unpack = True)
axes[1].plot(z, mass1, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass2, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass3, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass4, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass5, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass6, 'go')
axes[1].plot(z, mass7, 'go')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg1(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg2(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg3(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg4(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg5(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg6(xnew), 'k')
axes[1].plot(xnew, fg7(xnew), 'k')
```

[image]

Comment: From the file I'm drawing from, there are a few NaN data. Perhaps this is stopping the interpolation??

Comment: Perhaps. These seem to be stellar masses, yet you are plotting them as a function of redshift. What is this for?

Comment: Good eye. I'm plotting how the masses of supermassive blackholes evolve over time.

Comment: Ah, cool. Simulation data? Sorry to hijack the comment section, I'm working with a cosmology group right now and it is the subject of most of my SO questions as well :P

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I realized that some points of data were math.nan. They didn't allow interpolation.

I had to take my main file and cut it into different separate files where the redshift bin would match my mass bin. Hence, I took away math.nan and I could do the interpolation.

My solution is a pretty dumb one. If anybody could suggest a more efficient solution, feel free to please post it anyway.

Comment: What do you mean by your redshift bin "matching" your mass bin? I recently had a similar problem, after trying to calculate velocity dispersions of galaxy clusters given some galaxy spec data. About 3 out of 60 clusters were ending up with NaN dispersions, and I also solved it by binning. Though it seems overkill to manually divide your data into separate files. I just binned the redshifts using `numpy.histogram`

Comment: I meant "matching" in that for each redshift there would be a corresponding mass. For redshifts that had a NaN mass, I cut them out. I pretty much just split my original list and interpolated the cuts.

Comment: numpy.histogram seems really interesting... I'm a bit confused on the syntax for it though. How would I use numpy.histogram to cut my lists?